# Problem Importing Pylab in Python 2.6

Tags: python, ubuntu, matplotlib

I'm using Python 2.6 in Ubuntu 10.10.
I've run `help("modules")` in the Python interpreter and pylab and matplotlib are installed.

However, when I run `import pylab`, I get the following error message.

```
>>> import pylab
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/pylab.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib.pylab import *
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/matplotlib/pylab.py", line 206, in <module>
    from matplotlib import mpl  # pulls in most modules
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/matplotlib/mpl.py", line 3, in <module>
    from matplotlib import axes
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/matplotlib/axes.py", line 7928, in <module>
    Subplot = subplot_class_factory()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/matplotlib/axes.py", line 7920, in subplot_class_factory
    new_class = new.classobj("%sSubplot" % (axes_class.__name__),
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'classobj'
```

I don't know what's happening or how to fix it.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new.py file anywhere near where you are calling pylab module will break pylab and return this exact error.

Comment: It's not clear what you are saying. By "near" you mean in the pythonpath/working directory so that it is imported instead of pylab's new module?

Comment: It seems like either might be true.