# Error when I try to import Pearsonr from scipy.stats

Tags: python

I got this error, when I tried to import pearsonr from scipy.stats.

```
from scipy.stats import pearsonr
```

Error Shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
from stats import *
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/stats.py", line 198, in <module>
import distributions
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/distributions.py", line 87, in <module>
from new import instancemethod
File "new.py", line 2, in <module>
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 23, in <module>
from matplotlib.figure import Figure, figaspect
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/figure.py", line 18, in <module>
from axes import Axes, SubplotBase, subplot_class_factory
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 8537, in <module>
Subplot = subplot_class_factory()
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/axes.py", line 8529, in subplot_class_factory
new_class = new.classobj("%sSubplot" % (axes_class.__name__),
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'classobj'
```

Any solutions???

Comment: possibly helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655314/problem-importing-pylab-in-python-2-6

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you have a new.py file that is importing instead of the one needed.